# How to run tests on Edge using the browser library in robot framework

Tags: python, robotframework, playwright

I have been using browser library for executing my web UI tests on chrome browser in the robot framework. But now I want to run them on Edge. Since Browser library is based on playwright. And in playwright documentation it is mentioned like

```
|   =Browser=   | =Browser with this engine=                        |
| ``chromium``  | Google Chrome, Microsoft Edge (since 2020), Opera |
| ``firefox``   | Mozilla Firefox                                   |
| ``webkit``    | Apple Safari, Mail, AppStore on MacOS and iOS     |
```

But in the parameters we can only mention chromium, firefox or webkit. How can we specify that we want to run on Edge.

Comment: I would run on chromium, as that is essentially what Edge is

Comment: Have you done any research? When I searched the internet I got lots of results about how to run edge with playwright.

Answer (score 1):

you can use the channel msedge

robotframework example

New Browser    chromium    headless=false    channel=msedge

New Context    viewport={'width': 1920, 'height': 1080}

New Page       https://marketsquare.github.io/robotframework-browser/Browser.html

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).